# Roblox Studio: DataStore request was added to queue. Error

Tags: roblox

I am making race clicker game
and I am trying to make if player go through gate, player could get the passion.
I am using RaycastHiboxV4
and my giving hitbox and leaderstats scripts are working

```
local replicatedstorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RaycastHitbox = require(replicatedstorage:WaitForChild("RaycastHitboxV4"))
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local gatePassed = replicatedstorage:WaitForChild("gatePassed")

local hitbox = script.Parent
local character = hitbox.Parent

if hitbox:FindFirstAncestorOfClass("Model") == character then
    player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)
end

local Params = RaycastParams.new()
Params.FilterDescendantsInstances = {hitbox,character}
Params.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist

local newHitbox = RaycastHitbox.new(script.Parent)
newHitbox.RaycastParams = Params
newHitbox.Visualizer = false
newHitbox.DetectionMode = 2
newHitbox:HitStart()

local leaderstats = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local passions = leaderstats:WaitForChild("Passion")

newHitbox.OnHit:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name == "WinGate" then
        local gateNumber = tonumber(hit.SurfaceGui.TextLabel.Text)
        if gateNumber == 20 then
            character.HumanoidRootPart.Velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
        end
        
        if gateNumber > 0 and gateNumber < 10 then
            passions.Value = passions.Value + 1
        elseif gatePassed >= 10 and gateNumber < 15 then
            passions.Value = passions.Value + 3
        elseif gatePassed >= 15 then
            passions.Value = passions.Value + 5
        end
    end
end)
```

I tried to find some spelling wrongs or find some errors but nothing happened
the only thing is I got the error "DataStore request was added to queue. If request queue fills, further requests will be dropped. Try sending fewer requests.Key = 2222391052"

Comment: This error is when you are sending too many requests to the Data stores, either to get data or save it. However, the code you shared doesn't have any calls to the DataStores. Is the RaycastHitboxV4 module accessing the DataStores?

Comment: Actually I have No Idea what "Data Store" is

Comment: cuz my Raycast is in replicatedstorage

Comment: See [the docs for DataStores](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/data/data-stores). In the Limits section, there's this note : `There are also limits applied to the data store model. If an experience exceeds these limits, the service automatically throttles the experience's data store usage, causing requests to be placed in a queue.` You should search your code for `SetAsync` or `GetAsync` or `UpdateAsync` or `IncrementAsync` because something is trying to make too many requests, and it doesn't appear to be in this code sample you've shared.

Comment: I found SetAsync and GetAsync but what do I need to do with them

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, this is a warning that if you send more than 1 request every 60 seconds, it'll appear. There isn't anything wrong with your code.