# Roblox Studio-DataStore request was added to queue

Tags: roblox, datastore

I am making Race clicker game
And this is my script of my code
and I am keep getting the error, "DataStore request was added to queue. If request queue fills, further requests will be dropped. Try sending fewer requests.Key = 2222391052"
And the leaderstats are not updating.

```
local dataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local leaderstatsDataStore = dataStoreService:GetDataStore("data")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder",player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local passions = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    passions.Name = "Passion"
    
    local upgrades = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    upgrades.Name = "Hero Upgrade"
    
    local MaxSpeed = Instance.new("IntValue",leaderstats)
    MaxSpeed.Name = "Max Speed"
    
    local leaderstatsData = leaderstatsDataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    if leaderstatsDataStore ~= nil then
        passions.Value = leaderstatsData[1]
        upgrades.Value = leaderstatsData[2]
        MaxSpeed.Value = leaderstatsData[3]
    end
end)


game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local values = {}
    for _, child in pairs(player.leaderstats:GetChildren()) do
        table.insert(values,child.Value)        
    end
    pcall(function()
        leaderstatsDataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, values)
    end)
end)

game:BindToClose(function()
    for _, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
        local values = {}
        for _, child in pairs(player.leaderstats:GetChildren()) do
            table.insert(values,child.Value)        
        end
        pcall(function()
            leaderstatsDataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId, values)
        end)        
    end
end)
```

Someone said that this is an error that happens if I send request more than 60 times a second.
But I can't really get what is sending so much requests.
So can anyone tell the changed code to me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roblox Studio: DataStore request was added to queue. Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343967/roblox-studio-datastore-request-was-added-to-queue-error)

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, that's a *warning*. (Errors are red, warnings are yellow.)

You are getting the warning because the server can't do multiple data store operations at once. Instead, it queues the operations and does them one by one. However, if the queue becomes too long, some requests get dropped. That's not happening in your case, so you don't have to care about it.